# Drag points with Lat/Lng inputs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been using [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) to enable dragging of points. Successful JS fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/swwebb1/0n1xhbrk/7/).

My question is, how do I convert this to run off input data which uses a co-ordinate system based on lat/longs?

I can display/project the points fine, but when I drag it, it pins to the top left corner. DevTools Console returns an error "Error:  attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN"." Same returned for attribute cy.

I think it's something to do with the dragged function, but all the permutations I've tried on it have failed.

```js
var width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
    height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight) - 90;

var tile = d3.geo.tile()
    .size([width, height]);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale((1 << 23) / 2 / Math.PI)
    .translate([-width / 2, -height / 2]);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function (d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);

var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px");

var points = container.append("svg")
    .attr("id", "points");

var nodes_data_latlng = [{ "lat1": -0.01, "lng1": 0.025 }];

drawnodeslatlng();

function drawnodeslatlng() {
    d3.select("#points").selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes_data_latlng)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection([d.lng1, d.lat1])[0] })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection([d.lng1, d.lat1])[1] })
        .attr("r", "10")
        .call(drag)
}

function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}
function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this)
        .attr("cx", d.lng1 = d3.event.x)
        .attr("cy", d.lat1 = d3.event.y);
} 
function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.geo.tile.v0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3 v3, the `.origin` method you have here...

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function (d) { return d; })
```

...requires an object with `x` and `y` properties. The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Drag-Behavior.md#origin) for that quite old and outdated version says:

> Frequently the origin accessor is specified as the identity function: `function(d) { return d; }`. This is suitable when the datum bound to the dragged element is already an object with `x` and `y` attributes representing its current position.

Therefore, the easiest solution is simply removing it:

```js
var width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
    height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight) - 90;

var tile = d3.geo.tile()
    .size([width, height]);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale((1 << 23) / 2 / Math.PI)
    .translate([-width / 2, -height / 2]);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);

var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("id", "container")
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px");

var points = container.append("svg")
    .attr("id", "points");

var nodes_data_latlng = [{ "lat1": -0.01, "lng1": 0.025 }];

drawnodeslatlng();

function drawnodeslatlng() {
    d3.select("#points").selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes_data_latlng)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection([d.lng1, d.lat1])[0] })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection([d.lng1, d.lat1])[1] })
        .attr("r", "10")
        .call(drag)
}

function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}
function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this)
        .attr("cx", d.lng1 = d3.event.x)
        .attr("cy", d.lat1 = d3.event.y);
} 
function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.geo.tile.v0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```